# How should i format my JSON in Vue using Axios to look like this?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vue.js, axios

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to format my JSON in Vue.js to send it this way:

[image]

At the moment I'm trying to do it with a FormData() object, but the result is still just:

[image]

My function looks like this:

```
register () {
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append('firstname', 'Coca');
        bodyFormData.append('lastname', 'Cola')
        console.log(jsonData)
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'backend/index.php?action=createUser',
          data: bodyFormData,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
          })
          .then(function (response) {
              //handle success
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (response) {
              //handle error
              console.log(response);
          });
      }
```

I've achieved the result on the first picture through jQuery AJAX calls, is this also possible with Axios in Vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, I actually had to make a FormData and populate it with stringified JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JSON.stringify` method and append your object to your form data.

```
bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and sending form data for your `data` parameter. To send JSON, set `data` to the object you want to serialize as JSON, and use `application/json` as your `content-type`.

```
async register () {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'backend/index.php?action=createUser',
      data: { firstname: 'Coca', lastname: 'Cola' },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    //handle error
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're wanting to send form data with a data property that's JSON instead of just sending JSON in your post body, then @ZdravkoPernikov has the right answer.